# Can we use Renderscript to implement security oriented parts of a code?

Tags: android, security, renderscript

It is recommended to implement sensitive or security oriented parts of an Android app code in C using NDK as it cannot be decompiled easily as Java code, you have more control of memory allocation etc.

But now we have also Renderscript which code is also written in C and after background compiling on the device, it is run directly on CPU/GPU.

Does Renderscript has similar advantages?
Is it good idea to implement sensitive parts of a code in Renderscript?
Is it possible to decompile Renderscript bytecode placed in `raw` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderScript kernels would probably not be difficult to decompile, since they are compiled to LLVM Intermediate Representation for packaging with the app (as a resource). Only at runtime is that byte code compiled again to native. LLVM-IR is easy to decompile and in fact a decompiler for it (called [CBackend](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_21/lib/Target/CBackend/)) used to ship with LLVM.

Furthermore, the glue classes that you use to interact with the kernels are Java decompilation will reveal the signatures, indices and even names of (some) functions and variables. This could probably be blocked by switching to the NDK RenderScript API.

**Update:**
NDK Renderscript seems to embed the IR inside the generated glue class as `static const unsigned char __txt[]`, which probably makes it *very* difficult to extract the bytecode from the binary. The bytecode may still be accessible when it is cached/passed to libbcc for execution, however.

Comment: Wouldn't it just take `objdump` to locate the file offsets, and a hex editor to copy and paste the IR bytes?